# Why does 'del' work differently in different scenario? Please guide

Tags: python-3.x

In the below given code:

```
a=0
def somefunction():
    a='xyz'
    print(a)
del a
somefunction()
print(a)
```

The output for above code is

> xyz
>
> print(a)
>
> NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Now in different code

```
a=0
def anotherfunction():
    global a
    a='xyz'
    print(a)

del a
anotherfunction()
print(a)
```

The output here is

> xyz
>
> xyz

Here `del` doesn't delete the `a` variable.

Whereas in the below code

```
a=0
def anotherfunction():
    global a
    a='xyz'
    print(a)

anotherfunction()
print(a)

del a
print(a)
```

The output here is

> xyz
>
> xyz
>
> print(a)
>
> NameError: name 'a' is not defined

Comment: Not sure what exactly is your question. `del` deletes the variable, then you reassign it by calling `anotherfunction`.

Comment: @Selcuk Ok. It is because I have code global a in anotherfunction().

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you need to know is scope and namespace in Python.
Please see the Python tutorial on python.org., especially pages 70 to 72.

I am reproducing them here for your benefit:

[image: Page 70 a]

[image: Page 70 b]

[image: Page 71 a]

[image: Page 71b]

[image: Page 72]

Comment: Please refrain from posting screenshots or links as the only explanation. If ever something happens to the (image) host, this answer would become useless. Also the contents of screenshots are not easily machine-readable or copy-pastable.

Comment: @Tejas Shetty, Thanks and can you please share the full link of the tutorial

Comment: agreed @BramVanroy. I am currently quite busy. So, I thought better to post something than not post anything at all.

Comment: @NisrinDhoondia Just go to python.org and search for documentation. This would be one of them.

Comment: Two years should be enough. Can you please fix it now? (But ***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the question/answer should appear as if it was written today.)